# How to make sure the Bomgar remote client is uninstalled

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to make sure that all Bomgar clients are no longer running or installed on my Linux computer. How do I do that?

I have made two support calls where I was asked to download and run the Bomgar software. From what I gather from my research, the software is uninstalled when the session ends. Most of this information came from BeyondTrust and their customers, support organizations. I'd like independent information on Bomgar. There is a Bomgar jump client that allows remote access to unattended hosts. Again this is based on BeyondTrust information.

EDIT: I don't know which directory the software was installed to. It was downloaded to my Downloads folder, but it is not there anymore. I want to make sure that it did not install to another directory.

EDIT: OK, I looked at the documentation. Thanks for the tip! I'm 99% sure that the client is uninstalled. I don't see any subdirectories in `/home/me` or `/opt/bomgar'. It looks like that is where the Jump Client gets installed usually. (See page 18 of the documentation. The documentation link is below.)

Comment: When you downloaded and ran the software, did you tell it where to install? That would be the most direct route, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software is installed to a custom directory (`--install-dir`); the way to remove it, based on [their documentation](https://www.beyondtrust.com/docs/remote-support/documents/features/rs-jump-clients.pdf), is to run their `uninstall` script:

```
echo y | /path/to/jumpclient/uninstall
```

(or)

```
/path/to/jumpclient/uninstall > /tmp/log
```

The uninstall script checks whether stdout is a tty (`[ -t 1 ]`); if it is, then it sends a confirmation prompt. The first command above will send a `y` to that prompt. If the script determines that stdout is *not* a tty, it skips the prompt; the second command above redirects stdout to a log file to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Bomgar has several products, but the one I've used is called **Privileged Remote Access**.

When you start the downloaded file, it installs the program to `~/.bomgar-acc/` (and puts a desktop shortcut in `~/.local/share/applications`) and on exit it deletes the installer (from ~/Downloads or wherever).

Simply

```
rm -r ~/.bomgar-acc 
rm ~/.local/share/applications/bomgar-acc-support.nutreco.com.desktop
```

should delete it, though there's also an uninstall script in `~/.bomgar-acc/*/uninstall` that you may want to read first.

---

(Btw, the newest version, 19.1.3, has an oversized GUI on my laptop screen, slightly bad hidpi support I guess – I worked around this by putting `export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS='eDP-1=0.75'` in `~/.xprofile` to scale it down to 75% on my laptop screen called `eDP-1`; run `xrandr` to see what your screen is called.)

Comment: Is this another name for the "Bomgar jump client" from the question?

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: @JeffSchaller "Jump Client" is a jump method in bomgar remote access (there's also "Remote RDP" and "Protocol Tunnel Jump")